# Re-fill empty cells in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm working on a project which adds (sub) `JPanel` objects to another panel with `GridBagLayout`.  These sub-panels are removable, leaving a blank spot in the layout, like so:

[image]

When I add another panel into this, I would like it to first fill any empty spaces that exist, then continue filling sequentially like it does already.

I can figure out how to do this with one empty space, just not quite with many of them.

Here's what I can best figure: have an `ArrayList` to hold the x-y co-ords from removed objects (can you get that? get the `GridBagConstraints` from a component?)

Comment: The screenshot with 'gaps' amongst the Sound Track details components looks very strange to me.  I'd consider instead using a `JList` that allows horizontal wrap in this case.

Comment: BTW - by `GridBagCoordinates` DYM `GridBagConstraints`?

Comment: You'd need to re-adjust the x/y position of all the components each time a group is removed

Comment: Oh, yeah, not GridBagCoordinates ... that's what happens at 1 am I suppose.

Comment: You can [edit your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27701422/edit) at any time of day.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before remove the sub panel you can get the constraints using GridBagLayout's method

```
public GridBagConstraints getConstraints(Component comp)
```

and store them in a list (let's name it freeConstraintsList).

On add get free Constraints from the list and use to add the new sub panel (of couse removing the used constraints from the freeConstraintsList).

If the list is empty introduce the new Constraints.